# Cakephp session cookie name using wrong

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, session-cookies

My cakephp session cookie using PHPSESSID instead of user defined

here is the image, i try to get session name used by this application `debug(session_name());`, it show PHPSESSID instead of makassarterkini

[image]

is there something i need to configure in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your CakePHP [session configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html).

For example:

```
//core.php
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'stackoverflowexample',
    'timeout' => '43200',
    'cookieTimeout' => '43200'
));
```

I can access this session using:

```
$this->Session->read('stackoverflowexample.somevalue');
```